# short exact sequences and functors

Tags: category-theory

Suppose 
$$0 \longrightarrow A \longrightarrow B\longrightarrow C \longrightarrow 0$$
is a short exact sequence and $F$ is a functor, so we get maps $F(A)\longrightarrow F(B)$ and $F(B) \longrightarrow F(C)$. Is the sequence $$F(A)\longrightarrow F(B)\longrightarrow F(C)$$ exact in general?

Comment: No. Why would we bother with the name "half-exact functor" if it was automatic?

Answer (score 4):

You can find a couple of examples at [MO/46019](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46019).

Note that since you didn't assume that $F$ is additive, there are lots of trivial examples (for example non-zero constant functors).